# Gives a black screen when starting view controller swift

Tags: swift, screen, mvp

When I switch from one screen to another, I get a black screen, I can't figure out why

Controller:

```
class AddContactsController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Constants
    private enum Constants {
        static let textField = "nameTextCell"
        static let datePicker = "datePicker"
        static let pickerView = "pickerView"
        static let textViewNotes = "textViewNotes"
        static let alertOk = "OK"
        static let alertQuestion = "It seems you made a mistake"
        static let navigationTitle = "Create"
    }
    
    // MARK: - AddPresenter
    var presenter: AddListPresenter?
    
    func instantiate() -> UIViewController {
        let vc = AddContactsController()
        let presenter = AddListPresenter()
        vc.presenter = presenter
        return vc
    }
```

Presenter:

```
class AddListPresenter {
    
    weak var view: AddListController?
    private var contact: Contact
    
    init(contact: Contact? = nil) {
        self.contact = contact ?? .init(
            name: "",
            surname: "",
            middleName: "",
            phone: "",
            email: "",
            date: "",
            sex: "",
            notes: ""
        )
    }
    
    private var saveHieght: CGFloat = 0
```

How can this be avoided. I don't want to transfer presenter declarations to `viewDidLoad`

Comment: is `AddContactsController` storyboard based?

Comment: It's done in programmatically

Answer (score 0):

When you create a view controller by invoking it's initializer directly( e.g `AddContactsController()`, it's content view does not get created automatically like it would from a storyboad or a nibfile.

If you are creating you UI in code you need to show us your `loadView()` method. That's where you code to create your view hierarchy belongs.

Unless you have implemented `loadView()` you won't get any content view and will see a black screen exactly as you describe.

You also need to show the code that calls your `instantiate()` method and what you do with the view controller instance that's returned.